# How to read from NioSocketChannel?

Tags: netty

I am using a NioSocketChannel.
I must use it, since it is the only one that works with netty's Bootstrap in this code:

```
    Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
    b.group(group).channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
```

When I am getting the message, in a NioSocketChannel I can't read from it.
There is no read to a buffer in this class, there is only simple read(), that returns Channel and when I try to use it it throws exception that: "channel not registered to an event loop"

Does someone is familiar with this class?
Thanks,
Osnat.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to register a handler managing the event loop. You then do not read directly from the channel, but connect to the channel and register an observer to it. Details depend on your actual environment, but it roughly might look like:

```
Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
b.group(group).channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class).handler(/*  your handler */)

ChannelFuture channelFuture = b.connect(socketAddress, new InetSocketAddress(address, port));
responseFuture.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() { 
   // ... listen to changes                         
}
```

There are a lot of good code snippets on [programcreek](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel), those  should get you startet.